# react-native: possibility to have a a sidebar for react-native for website?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I test an example of a navigation like a sidebar with react-native with Drawer.Navigator

example:

```
<Drawer.Navigator
                drawerContentOptions={{
                    activeTintColor: '#e91e63',
                    itemStyle: { marginVertical: 5 },
                }}
                drawerContent={(props) => <CustomSidebarMenu {...props} />}>
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name="FirstPage"
                    options={{ drawerLabel: 'First page Option' }}
                    component={firstScreenStack}
                />
                <Drawer.Screen
                    name="SecondPage"
                    options={{ drawerLabel: 'Second page Option' }}
                    component={secondScreenStack}
                />
            </Drawer.Navigator>
```

My customSidebar:

```
    import React from 'react';
import {
    SafeAreaView,
    View,
    StyleSheet,
    Image,
    Text,
    Linking,
} from 'react-native';

import {
    DrawerContentScrollView,
    DrawerItemList,
    DrawerItem,
} from '@react-navigation/drawer';

const CustomSidebarMenu = (props) => {
    const BASE_PATH =
        'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/AboutReact/sampleresource/master/';
    const proileImage = 'react_logo.png';

    return (
        <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {/*Top Large Image */}
            <Image
                source={{ uri: BASE_PATH + proileImage }}
                style={styles.sideMenuProfileIcon}
            />
            <DrawerContentScrollView {...props}>
                <DrawerItemList {...props} />
                <DrawerItem
                    label="Visit Us"
                    onPress={() => Linking.openURL('https://aboutreact.com/')}
                />
                <View style={styles.customItem}>
                    <Text
                        onPress={() => {
                            Linking.openURL('https://aboutreact.com/');
                        }}>
                        Rate Us
                    </Text>
                    <Image
                        source={{ uri: BASE_PATH + 'star_filled.png' }}
                        style={styles.iconStyle}
                    />
                </View>
            </DrawerContentScrollView>
            <Text style={{ fontSize: 16, textAlign: 'center', color: 'grey' }}>
                www.aboutreact.com
            </Text>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
};
```

If I build for the web, the result is not good for web.

Mode close, initiale in the webpage
[image]

Mode open
[image]

I can't find a solution to adapt this in web. To have a sidebar open in the same index. It's not a good pratices but  Maybe it's not possible.  Anybody had the same problem ?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React Navigation gives you the option to decide which type of drawer you want with the [drawerType](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/drawer-navigator#drawertype) prop from the `Drawer` component.

You can add some logic to change the value of `drawerType` based on the Platform and you should be able to achieve what you want